# Is it possible to make functions in a dynamic library auto-detectable for Python?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

When I want to use rust code in Python I would write something like the following in rust

```
#![crate_type = "dylib"]

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn fib(n: u32) -> u32 {
    if n <= 1 {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }
}
```

and then something like the following in Python to use the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes

fiblib = ctypes.CDLL("./libfibonacci.so")
fib = fiblib.fib
n = 37
print("The %ith Fibonacci number is %i." % (n, fib(n)))
```

However, I have to know that there is a function `fib` which takes one integer as an argument and returns an integer.

Is it possible to auto-detect which functions are in a dynamic library?

Is it possible to write / compile rust (or C) code in such a way that it is automatically detectable with Python?

Comment: You have to provide that information because the shared library doesn't know it. It doesn't store function argument types, just their names and addresses.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you can use tools like `objdump --dynamic-syms` to list all dynamic symbols im-/exported by a shared library.

Symbols in the `.text` section are exported and functions have the flags `DF`:

```
0000000000005586 g    DF .text  0000000000000024  Base        gtkspell_attach
```

Imported functions can be identified by `DF *UND*`:

```
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_free
```

The only way to figure out what arguments the function takes and what it returns is to look at the debug information which is optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `readelf`; however it would not be trivial to use this programatically from Python and it looks like it only gies you function names for C and mangled names for C++.

See: [Introspection of the interface of a shared library](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61940/introspection-of-the-interface-of-a-shared-library)

**NB:** The information in the shared library does not store information about function parameters for C; for C++ whilst you get *mangled* names you can use `c++filt` to *demangle* and get function parameters.

---

However you may want to have a look at [ctypesgen](https://github.com/davidjamesca/ctypesgen) a tool which can be used to *automatically* generate a [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) module for you given the Header file(s) `.h`.